# custom variable with class selector to change nth value on runtime

Tags: javascript, css

Can we use global variable, passing the integer value `:root{--nthVal: 1;}`

```
div:nth-of-type(1) { ... } ==> div:nth-of-type(var(--nthVal)) { ... }
```

passing the value to `--nthVal` from js.

```
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--nthVal', 1);
```

custom variable is updating the value but desire result is not coming.

Comment: you cannot use custom property there

Comment: I don't think you can modify a stylesheet like this, but if you are using javascript anyway why not use js to put the appropriate style on the element?